# Are our answer and voting rates healthy?

Tags: discussion

I don't have any numbers to back this up, but I just have a feeling that some of our site's answer and voting rates may be slipping. It may just be a symptom of a maturing site, or perhaps an influx of [software questions](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/753) that just aren't all that interesting.

Does anyone know if these stats are available and if they are, as I suspect, on the decline?

Comment: related: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/859/does-gis-have-a-low-voting-problem

Comment: I sort of agree with you, and can suggest a reason; Where are the good questions? I haven't seen a single interesting, though-provoking question in weeks!

Comment: @Devdatta "Interesting" is in the eye of the beholder. Among interesting recent questions I noted http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53217/ (of cartographic and analytical interest), http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/52949 (somewhat technical but revealing), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52244/, and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51929/ (raster version of a site FAQ), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53274/ (what average to use?), and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53163/.  Perhaps you could contribute a good question? :-)

Comment: I agree that interesting is highly subjective. Raster statistic questions may be interesting -- though I don't know anything about, but software, apis, dbs and programming is the arena of gis implementation and extremely valuable to me and many others. It's like having a physics Q&A and trying to exclude math related questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, voting has dipped about 20% since mid-January.

It did that in 2011 and 2012, too. :-)

I, too, have an impression that we are receiving a spate of poor and uninteresting questions.  Such trends should not be a surprise, since others have noted that some FOSS developers are referring users to our site for support: that virtually guarantees we will get an increasing load of mundane, duplicated, one-off, and poorly researched software-specific questions in proportion to the rate at which that software is adopted.  But if we were to ban all such questions, site traffic would slow to a trickle and then where would we be?

Comment: Interesting pattern if this happens every year, does that mean that people start out in new jobs/courses and in over their head?

Comment: @underdark its true : )