# Is it possible to program website behavior in response to lists of tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, questions

In [Do multiple GIS software tags equal multiple questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4568) the issue is raised as to how to respond to certain combinations of tags, in particular the presence of tags for multiple GIS software systems.

Is it possible to program the web site software to recognize certain combinations and pop-up a message to the OP?

In the cited case, the trigger would be the presence of two or more tags from a set comprising software systems and the message would be to either replace them all with [gis-principle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gis-principle) or select the tag for the software system of primary interest.

Comment: This would be better asked on Meta SE as it's Stack Exchange functionality rather than GIS SE specific.  That said, sometimes tagging multiple GIS software is correct e.g. How to do x from ArcGIS when using QGIS, or how to import QGIS data into ArcGIS Desktop etc.  It would be impossible to have a blanket rule that multiple tags = too broad or multiple tags = GIS principle.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that it would be possible, but not at the GIS SE site level.

For a network-wide change to allow per-site customization of triggers on tag combinations you would need to find/make a feature request at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

I think it would be a hard enhancement to make the case for.