# Using tags for large datasets and big data?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

We currently have tags for:

- [large-datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets) with 73 questions

> difficult to process and manage because the size is usually bigger
>   than the limits software can normally deal with.

- [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) with 41 questions

> A collection of data sets so large and complex that it becomes
>   difficult to process using on-hand database management tools or
>   traditional data processing applications.

On [three questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets+big-data) both tags have been applied.

Are both needed or should one become a synonym of the other?

Comment: big data is more analytical to say an 18Terrabyte Lidar file.

Comment: With no more than a net 2 vote on any answer there seems little impetus to act on this one at this time.

Answer (score 2):

[Big Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) is a recognised technical term and analytical field.

A large dataset is just a large dataset.

I do not think they should be combined, however I believe that if they are combined, [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) should be the master tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Midavalo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4838/115) that:

> [Big Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) is a recognised technical term and analytical field.
>
> A large dataset is just a large dataset.
>
> ... and that if they are combined, [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) should be the master
>   tag.

However, I would go further and propose that they **are combined** by:

1. Merging the [large-datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets) tag into the [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) tag and leaving [large-datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets) as a synonym.
2. For any questions where later ad hoc review suggests that a "large dataset" is not large or complex enough to qualify as Big Data, then the [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) tag should be removed and the largeness of the data involved just be identified by words like "large dataset" in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

While 'big-data' and 'large-datasets' are different things/concepts as mentioned in [Midavalo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4837/using-tags-for-large-datasets-and-big-data/4838#4838), I think such differences are not reflected in the current way questions are tagged [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) and [large-datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets) in GIS SE.

My opinion is that [big-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) is just being used for expressing 'large-datasets' and doing stuff in software with it. The theoretical part (analytical/science part) is completely missing from those questions.

This is not a surprise given our huge bias toward software/applied questions (for example, we even have a tag when the question is abstract --> [Is it useful to have a [gis-principle] tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/is-it-useful-to-have-a-gis-principle-tag)).

Moreover, how are we going to draw the line between using one over another and making questions being tagged consistently, so tags become useful for searching both subjects?

**Proposal**:

Therefore, I vote for synonymizing tags (keep them unmerged for a few months so we can see how it goes) making [large-datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-datasets) the master one. A new excerpt could be written to welcome both types of concepts.